# onChange not working for auto populated fields

Tags: javascript, sum, onchange

I created a beneficiaries form that auto populates designated percentages when a user chooses a beneficiary.  For example, a user can choose Child 1, and based on the percentage share they designated for Child 1 in another table, it auto populates that percentage in this form (function beneficiary_1()).  I created a separate onChange script for each of the percentage fields to sum up all of the percentages, but I don't think it works with auto populated fields...

```
function percentSum(){
    var arr = document.getElementsByName('beneficiary_share');
    var tot=0;
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
            tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
    }
    document.getElementById('total_percentage').value = tot;
}
```

Is there a way I can modify this so it works with auto populated fields?

HTML:

```
<tr>
  <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000000;">
    <g:ui_reference name="family_member_1" id="family_member_1" table="hr_beneficiary" query = "active=true^employee=javascript:gs.getUserID()" completer="AJAXTableCompleter" columns="employee; beneficiary_contact.relationship" onChange="beneficiary_1()" />
  </td>
  <td class = "inside"><input class = "sf2823"  type="text" id="fm1_ssn" name ="fm1_ssn" style="background-color:#dddddd" readonly="readonly"/>
  </td>
  <td class = "inside"><input class = "sf2823" type="text" id="fm1_address" name ="fm1_address" style="background-color:#dddddd" value="" readonly="readonly"/>
  </td>
  <td class = "inside"><input class = "sf2823" type="text" id="fm1_relationship" name ="fm1_relationship" style="background-color:#dddddd" value="" readonly="readonly"/>
  </td>
  <td><input class = "sf2823" type="text" id="fm1_percentage" name ="beneficiary_share" style="background-color:#dddddd" value="" readonly="readonly" onChange="percentSum()"/>  
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Plunker/jsfiddle please.

Comment: onchange is not triggered by values modified in code, you will have to trigger it yourself

Answer (score 0):

You have to listen from a higher DOM element.

For example:

```
$(document).on('change', '#beneficiary_share', percentSum);
```

When you add that new element the percentSum function will be called.

Comment: Hey Alex, can you expand on that?  I'm not fluent in JS so I'm not understanding exactly what you mean.  thanks!

Comment: Well, it's kind of hard to tell with the way you worded the question, you should post a working js fiddle for us to understand better. But if I'm understanding right you're generating new HTML markup after your user interacts with the page. If that's the case then this new HTML will not be listening for changes because the Javascript code has already been run. So instead you listen to any document (the highest html element) changes, and IF something happens to the html then you call that function on the target HTML, which is the second parameter in the above function.

Comment: Well for a start... this is **jQuery** which isn't tagged in the question so an explanation would be useful for those who don't know/use the jQuery plugin/library.

Comment: Hey Alex, i thought about posting a fiddle, but none of the fields would auto populate so it wouldn't make much sense.  What you described is correct though -- what is the syntax for your code above?

Comment: Hey Dave, sorry I overlooked the tags on your question @NewToJS is right. The language is Jquery, and you'd have to require it through a CDN or by downloading it. So...1.$(document) selects the document via Jquery. 2. .on "change" detects any changes to it. 3. "#beneficiary_share" is the element targeted if any changes occur to document. 4. percentSum is the function that would be executed if any changes occur to document. 5.In the percentSum function you can access "#beneficiary_share" via the "this" keyword, and alter it from there. :)